# Phone Call - Swift 3 with xCode 8.1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

How can I to make a phone call with swift 3.0
I used the following code in Swift 3.0

```
UIApplication.shared.open(openURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

But its not running on xCode 8.1

How can I make a call in swift 3.0?

Comment: What is `openURL`?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
guard let url = URL(string: "telprompt://" + number) else { return }
UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

For popup use `telprompt://\(number)` and for direct call use `tel://\(number)`